# Publish/Subscribe pattern with subscriber response

Tags: messaging, publish-subscribe, mqtt, iot

Is this possible in a publish/subscribe pattern?

1. A publisher publishes a message to a topic;
2. Subscriber(s) receive(s) the message;
3. The subscribers reply to publisher with a custom message.

Is step 3 possible? I'm designing a system that will use **MQTT** protocol (communication between smartphones and microcontrollers). However, the subscriber needs to send an answer to the publisher other than the Acknowledged message.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly reply to the a message in a MQTT system, but there is nothing to stop you using 2 topics (outboud/inbound) and including a message id in the payload of the message to identify the reply to the original published message

Comment: I believe you can use the same topic. You don't need to create a separate one. But you will need to do the message handling manually.

Comment: You can use the same topic, but the code is simpler if you split them, especially if your working on an embedded device

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this if you incorporate a queue manager, the message could be sent back directly from the queue manager to the client using the ClientID.